# How to fetch all geopoints from firestore into google map in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, google-maps-markers

In flutter I tried below code to fetch geolocation on a map

```
getLocations(){
    Firestore.instance
    .collection('posts')
    .gerDocuments()
    .then((docs){
        if (docs.documents.isNotEmpty){
            for(int i = 0; i < docs.documents.length; ++i){
                setupMarkers(docs.documents[i].data, docs.documents[i].documentID);
            }
        }
    });
}


void setupMarkers(data, id){
    var markerNameID = id;
    final MarkerID markerId = MarkerId(markerNameID);
    final Marker marker = Marker(
        marker: mmarkerId,
        position:
            LatLng(data['location'].latitude, data['location'].longitude),
        infoWindow:
            InfoWindow(title: "Fetched Markers", snippet: data['address']),
    );
    setState((){
        markers[markerId] = marker;
    });
}
```

But I have 2 problems,

1. This **getLocations()** method is no longer available in new firebase plugin.
2. I changed my firestore data structure as below image. (I created sub collection)

[image]

This is my new structure & I am stuck with fetching markers on my map. How can I change the code according to the new method and structure.

Comment: "This method is no longer available in new firebase plugin." what method do you mean?

Comment: @Victor Eronmosele   I mean **getLocations()**

Comment: `getLocations()` is a method you created yourself. Please take a look at the link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and add relevant error messages, your expected behaviour and your current behaviour.